# joomla 2.5 404 error only in single article menu item

Tags: joomla, http-status-code-404, hebrew

I have a website that has several language versions.
One of them is in hebrew and there i have the following problem.
The main menu items work fine with category blog or single contact but show a "404 error" page if you click on a "single article" type of menu item.
I disabled the SEF and URL rewriting options in global configuration but it didn't help - the same error occurs again.

I have installed Hebrew language pack, also added Hebrew content language and enabled the language plug ins. Nothing helps. It is strange that it doesn't work neither with or without the SEF and URL rewriting options.

Can you help me solve this problem?

Here's the URL of the website: http://funtopiaworld.photonhost.com/kfarsaba/he/

Comment: Does the article actually exist?

Comment: You have to check if article is available for the language you are trying to open it.